# Animation-hidden uiview within another uiview?

Tags: ios, animation

I've 2 views,A and B.

```
A(Aframe)--------------->B(Bframe)------>C(cFrame)
```

I want to execute an animation.A will moves from Aframe to Cframe.
But at B,A will be hidden

```
A(Aframe)------(non-hidden area)---------->B(Bframe)------(hidden area)-------->C(Cframe)
```

How to do that?
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
// I suppose viewA, viewB, viewC is subviews of self.view
UIView *viewA = ..., *viewB = ..., *viewC = ...;
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:viewA];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    viewA.frame = viewC.frame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:viewA];
}];
```